# how to prevent opening "save as" dialogue box while downloading an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I just wanted to download all the images of web page via javascript but got stuck at point. When i download all the images "save as" dialogue box opens, Since i want to download all images at once therefore many "save as" dialogue box opens and crash the browser and which in turn crashes the system.

Please note:- i have to do this by injecting javascript in webpage. Therefore onload plugins is not working

My js code is

```
for (i = 0; i < all_img_tags.length; i++) {
     console.log(all_img_tags[i].getAttribute('src'));  
     if(all_img_tags[i].width>0){
         var filename = 'file_'+i;
         var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
         downloadLink.download = filename;
         downloadLink.href = all_img_tags[i].getAttribute('src');
         downloadLink.click();
     }
}
```

i have tried this also

```
if(all_img_tags[i].width>0){    
    convertImgToBase64URL(all_img_tags[i].getAttribute('src'), function(base64Img){
        var blob = dataUriToBlob(base64Img);
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     });
}

function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
   img.src = url;
}
```

Comment: `Save As` is browser feature, not JS feature. Set to auto-save files in your browser.

Comment: but i have to write the script which should be independent of browser so that other people can also use this

Comment: Shouldn't you search the existing answers first? [google-chrome-extension download multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-chrome-extension%5D+download+multiple+files)

Comment: @vishal You can put these files to zip file and than download single archive

Comment: @ wOxxOm yeah but didn't find anything usefull

Comment: @Justinas how can i do this ? do you know any method

Comment: For security reasons, it's unlikely that any browser will let you inject code that will download and save a file to a user's local drive without first asking the user's permission. If you find a browser that allows unconfirmed downloads, tell us about it so we can tell our clients not to use it! ;-)